# Camera matrix initialization in EMGU CV

Tags: c#, image-processing, emgucv

I am trying to use method findEssentialMat in my program. I have two images, two arrays of features and focus. But this method requires camera matrix (type: IInputArray) as an attribute. So the question is how to initialize the camera matrix manually, without camera calibration?

This code doesn't work because double[,] is the wrong type for the representation of cameraMatrix.

```
        double[,] camMat = {
            { focal, 0,  imgInput1.Size.Width / 2 },
            { 0,    focal,   imgInput1.Size.Height / 2 }, 
            { 0, 0, 1 }
        };

        VectorOfPointF vpfpoints1 = new VectorOfPointF(mKPstoPF(foundedFeatures1));
        VectorOfPointF vpfpoints2 = new VectorOfPointF(currFeat);

        CvInvoke.FindEssentialMat(points1: vpfpoints1,
                                  points2: vpfpoints2,
                                  cameraMatrix: camMat,
                                  method: Emgu.CV.CvEnum.FmType.Ransac,
                                  prob: 0.999,
                                  threshold: 1,
                                  mask: null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used this way to define camera matrix:

```
    Matrix<double> matr = new Matrix<double>(3, 3);
        matr[0, 0] = focal;
        matr[0, 1] = 0;
        matr[0, 2] = imgInput1.Size.Width / 2;
        matr[1, 0] = 0;
        matr[1, 1] = focal;
        matr[1, 2] = imgInput1.Size.Width / 2;
        matr[2, 0] = 0;
        matr[2, 1] = 0;
        matr[2, 2] = 1;
```